# React Hot reload doesn't apply changes

Tags: reactjs, webpack, hot-reload

I created an app with create-react-app --template typescript and then ejected.

I noticed that, when I change tsx everything is good. But with ts files, it's not working properly. For example, if I put a new line with console.log, it will print in the browser.

But if I change some logic in the function, I will see the old behavior. In source of browser I see new `main.<hash>.hot-update.js` file. So it was delivered to the client, but did not get applied.

Please give me an advice on where I should search next or which plugin I should explore for webpack!

Answer (score 0):

I found where the problem is, and it looks like it's not a bug, but normal behavior. The whole problem was in the signaltone. I created an instance of the class in another file, then it is he who is not updated.

```
// class.ts
export class Foo {
  print() {
    console.log('Instance of Foo');
  }
}

// instance.ts
import { Foo } from './class.ts';

export const foo = new Foo();

// component.tsx
import React from 'react';
import foo from './instance.ts'

export const Component = () => {
  const onClick = () => {
    foo.print() 
  }

  return <div onClick={onClick}>Some Content</div>;
}
```